# button long-pressed to control the loop of blinking

Tags: button, arduino, long-press

i already asked about this program in one question about the blinking LED to be controlled by a button, but now i want to ask if my program is capable of having the long-press for 5 seconds and then it will start the blinking loop and if the button is long-pressed for less than or more than 5 seconds.

```
int buttonPin = D0;    
int ledPin = D1; 
int held = 5;

int ledState = LOW;         
int buttonState;             
int lastButtonState = LOW;   


long lastDebounceTime = 0;  
long debounceDelay = 50;   

void setup() 
{
pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);

pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);


digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
}

void loop() 
{

int reading = digitalRead(buttonPin);

if (reading != lastButtonState) 
{
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
} 

if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) 
{

    if (reading != buttonState) 
    {
        buttonState = reading;
        if (buttonState == HIGH && held == 5) 
        {
          BLINK;
          if {
          A;
          }
          else {
          B;
          }
        }


    }
   }

   digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
   lastButtonState = reading;
 }

 void BLINK(){
            int cntr=5;
            do
            {
                digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);   
                delay(200);  
                digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);    
                delay(200);                
                cntr = cntr-1;
            } 
            while (cntr!=0);
            digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
            delay(900000);
            ledState = LOW;
   }
   void A(){
   if (held < 5){
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

   }
   }

   void B(){
   if (held > 5){
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try holding up the process with a while loop

```
if(digitalread(buttonPin) == HIGH){
    timerStart = millis();
    while(digitalread(buttonPin == HIGH){}
    timerEnd = millis();
}
```

Then compare timerStart and timerEnd